# What does the "plus sign" do in the new Spotify?

Tags: spotify

Spotify's mobile app and desktop client underwent [a pretty drastic (black) redesign](http://www.fastcompany.com/3028603/most-creative-people/inside-the-redesign-why-spotify-went-black). Overall, it's a welcome upgrade. But one change isn't intuitive: Instead of stars there are now "plus signs." When you click them, they turn into check marks, but that seems to be it. "Plussed" songs do not fall into the "Starred" playlist, as we're used to.

What does "plus" do? And how can I "star"?

Comment: Worst (re)design ever by Spotify. Makes absolutely no sense. And not a helpful tooltip anywhere =(

Comment: You can still drag songs to the Starred playlist.

Comment: The fact that this question has 23 upvotes and its answer 32, shows Spotify should change the design - at least add a tooltip, for crying out loud.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this out, and only after digging into [the official community help forum](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/Removing-stars-in-new-Spotify-version/m-p/697828#M75867) did it all make sense.

Stars are a thing of the past for Spotify, and the company is gradually phasing them out. **"Plus" is the new star, and plussed songs fall into the songs collection under the new "Your Music" folder.** Plussed albums are collected in the "Albums" folder in "Your Music."

[image: Spotify - Your Music]

This change may have been made to distinguish "Like" in radio, which influences future plays, from actually "Liking" and wanting to save a song or artist. (One guess.) Presumably, the old "Starred" playlist will soon disappear, or else fall below old playlists so as to hide from view.

To continue having easy access to these old "Starred" songs, it's recommended that you go into the folder, select all, and copy or drag and drop them into the new "Songs" under "Your Music." But don't expect to be able to sort by original date "starred" -- the new date added will overwrite the old metadata.

One major thing that differs the "starred" playlist and the "plussed" is that the plussed will not show up on your profile as the starred one. It's also not possible to set the plussed songs to be available offline.

Comment: 'Starred' now seems to act like an ordinary playlist, so you can still sort of use it like before, except that to add tracks to it you need to do 'Add to... > Starred'.

Comment: That and also deal with duplicate tracks on lists best I can tell.  Personally I am done with Spotify.  Just to heavy and clunky now.  Annoys me.  Whole "social media" integration is a waste of time far as I am concerned.

Comment: @ficuscr What do you like better than Spotify?

Answer (score 1):

When selecting the '+' Sign I noticed that all those songs could be located on the Left Sidebar under Your Library in Songs.

Select Songs and all "Saved" songs should display.

Selecting the '+' Sign or Heart icon "Saves" the designated Song to the above specified location.

> *I am very new to Spotify, so I am unfamiliar with the Star System.*

```
EDIT: I have also noticed that songs that are "Hearted" seem to also "Save" them.
They can be located in the Songs Page under Your Library in the Left Sidebar.

Also made some minor styling changes and clarified my post for the convenience of others.
```

Updated on: 6Jun19